# How to open a Progressive Web Apps (PWA) app from a QR reader in iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

### What I want to do

I want to launch the PWA app installed in my home when I scan a QR code on iOS.

In Android, when a QR code is scanned, the user is given the option of opening the PWA app or Chrome, so I want to make this happen in IOS as well.
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### Problems

On iOS, the PWA app added to the home screen does not launch and opens the website in Safari.

### Solution

As far as I could find, I couldn't find a way to achieve this, so if anyone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know. Thank you in advance.